# Building bazel rule that depends on another rule

Tags: node.js, build, bazel

I'm trying to build a bazel rule for codegen'ing GraphQL types, using the `graphql-codegen` library.

The implementation of the `gqlgen` rule is straightforward:

```py
load("@bazel_skylib//lib:paths.bzl", "paths")
load("@build_bazel_rules_nodejs//:defs.bzl", "nodejs_binary")

_SCHEMA = """
  {types}:
    schema: {schema}
    plugins:
      - "typescript"
  {meta}:
    schema: {schema}
    plugins:
      - "introspection"
"""

_CONFIG = """
overwrite: true
generates:
  {instructions}
"""

def _gqlgen_impl(ctx):
    config_file = ctx.actions.declare_file(ctx.label.name + ".yml")

    out_files = []
    instructions = []
    for s in ctx.files.srcs:
        name = paths.basename(s.path)[:-len(".graphql")]
        types = ctx.actions.declare_file("types/{}.ts".format(name))
        meta = ctx.actions.declare_file("meta/{}.json".format(name))
        out_files.append(types)
        out_files.append(meta)
        instructions.append(_SCHEMA.format(schema = s.path, types = types.path, meta = meta.path))
    instructions = "\n".join(instructions)

    ctx.actions.write(
        content = _CONFIG.format(instructions = instructions),
        output = config_file,
    )

    ctx.actions.run_shell(
        tools = [ctx.executable._codegen],
        inputs = depset(ctx.files.srcs + [config_file]),
        outputs = out_files,
        command = "{gqlgen} --config {cfg}".format(
            gqlgen = ctx.executable._codegen.path,
            cfg = config_file.path,
        ),
    )
```

The input is a set of `*.graphql` files and the output is a corresponding set of `*.json` and `*.ts` files.

I'm using the nodejs rules, and since `graphql-codegen` is a node module, I'm declaring a rule for it in the `gqlgen` rule:

```py
def gqlgen(name, **kwargs):
    nodejs_binary(
        name = "gqlgen",
        data = ["@npm//:node_modules"],
        entry_point = "@npm//:node_modules/@graphql-codegen/cli/bin.js",
        install_source_map_support = False,
        visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    )

    _gqlgen(
        name = name,
        **kwargs
    )
```

My issue lies in tying these two things together. I have the following:

```py
_gqlgen = rule(
    implementation = _gqlgen_impl,
    attrs = {
        "srcs": attr.label_list(
            allow_files = [".graphql"],
        ),
        "_codegen": attr.label(
            cfg = "host",
            default = "//schemas:gqlgen",
            executable = True,
        ),
    },
)
```

Note, however, that for the `_codegen` attribute I'm specifying the executable as `//schemas:gqlgen`, which is wrong, since I should be able to use the `gqlgen` rule from any package.

Is there a way to refer to the `nodejs_binary` from the call to `rule()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my question, I can simply do the following:

```py
_gqlgen = rule(
    implementation = _gqlgen_impl,
    attrs = {
        "srcs": attr.label_list(
            allow_files = [".graphql"],
        ),
        "_codegen": attr.label(
            cfg = "host",
            executable = True,
        ),
    },
)

def gqlgen(name, **kwargs):
    nodejs_binary(
        name = "gqlgen",
        data = ["@npm//:node_modules"],
        entry_point = "@npm//:node_modules/@graphql-codegen/cli/bin.js",
        install_source_map_support = False,
        visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    )

    _gqlgen(
        name = name,
        _codegen = "gqlgen",
        **kwargs
    )
```

Comment: One note: it's conventional to name "internal" targets created by a macro as suffixes of the name of the "main" target, to avoid collisions using the macro multiple times in the same package. For example, `name = name + ".gqlgen"`.

Comment: Is your code gen rule available somewhere on github?